# Custom widgets can't be added to GWT Designer palette

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

I wrote some custom composite widgets for a project and compiled them into a separate jar file.  I added this jar file to the build path for the GWT project.  When I try to add the widgets to the palette (by pressing the "Choose component" button), I can pick the composite widget's class in the list, but I get the following error:

> WindowBuilder was unable to load com.test.common.ui.LocationBox.  This may be caused by 
>   ClassLoader problems.  Do you want to refresh editor and try again?

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there something I need to add to the jar to make it load properly?

Comment: You should be aware the GWT designer is not officially supported anymore. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175381/why-does-gwt-2-7-discontinue-the-designer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the GWT Designer does not pick up changed classes or is not able to find them.
I would recommend to a full rebuild using the menu "Project->Clean" and then closing and reopening the designer.
If this does not help, try a restart of eclipse before reopening the designer.