# What alternative to the GWT Designer do programmer use now?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

It's been a while since I last used GWT but I was thinking of using it again for another project. I now realized that there is no GWT Designer to use for Eclipse as it is discontinued.

First I thought that might not be such a problem but it is quite annoying to not have a preview of your `*.ui.xml` files and now I am not sure if I really want to use GWT without such a tool.

I was wondering what the workflow now looks like without GWT Designer for those who are using GWT.

As a side question I'd like to know if I should keep my fingers off GWT. [This post](http://www.guynirpaz.com/2012/04/28/gwt-is-dead/) e.g. has its good and maybe true points.

Comment: Why do you say GWT Designer for Eclipse is discontinued?

Comment: @StephenC I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175381/why-does-gwt-2-7-discontinue-the-designer

Comment: The post you are referencing is nearly 3 years old. It was written before GWT introduces SDM. And why do you think that GWT Designer is so important? I, personally, prefer coding my UI. If I have to use HTML from a designer, I can use something like Errai.

Comment: I use *.ui.xml files. With GWT 2.7 it is quite fast to reload the page. So it is not that far from using pure HTML IMO

Comment: @ElHoss Maybe I'm just not used to it but I found it very convenient using the Designer back then. You can click together the basic layout quite fast and then change the details either in the *.ui.xml code of using the UI itself. I am a little surprised that Google stops the development of it.

Comment: @RonanQuillevere It's funny.. I remember a few years ago everything developed towards better visual "Designer"-like environments to "click-together" your layout/design or am I mistaken by that? Writing HTML code feels like writing assembly to me but there you go .. I think I'll have to get used to is and learn some new UIBinder xml tags. ^^

Comment: @StefanFalk: As far as I know Google never developed GWT Designer. The GWT Designer was created by Instantiations and bought by Google. Now GWT Designer is an Open Source project and any development is done by the community.

Comment: @StefanFalk IMO WYSIWYG editors have never been enough powerfull for advanced scenarios. I think the browsers are the best UI editors :)

GWT *.ui.xml is not as good as pure HTML templates like in angular JS but it is not so bad. GTW is not good for productivity at first but gets better when the application becomes big 

Maybe Singular will change that :) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/singular-contrib/jPlRqPd9T3Y